# Libreoffice 3.3.2 Export to PDF option only lets me export entire documents

Tags: 11.04, libreoffice, pdf

After installing Natty 11.04 (Kubuntu), I noticed that the "Export to PDF" menu item does not present a dialog allowing me to select pages of the document.  I can export the entire document only.  I've looked through the Options, and I can't find any "switch" I've set to turn this off--not that I would want to...

I am thinking about doing an uninstall-reinstall, has anyone else had this problem--or know a solution?  TIA for any help

Comment: Wanted my old functionality back, so I saves the ~/.libreoffice directory to another location and did an apt-get purge libreoffice libreoffice-kde.  Then I opened KPackageKit and found them still marked as installed, so I marked every green-checked item as "Remove."   Once this was finished, everybody agreed it was gone, so I reinstalled everything using KPackageKit.   I tested first with a "vanilla" install, then restored my saved user macros and dialogs.  File->Export to PDF again gives me a dialog titled "PDF Options" which allows me quite a bit of control over PDF creation as it did before

Answer (score 2):

What I suggest you do is to install [pdfmod](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdfmod) [image: Install pdfmod]
 (Click to install), then you can delete any subsequent pages you no longer need.

Or you can install it via  the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfmod
```

Press Enter, then enter your password, pressing Enter again and PDF Mod will now be installed.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted my old functionality back, so I saved the ~/.libreoffice directory and did an apt-get purge libreoffice libreoffice-kde

Comment: IMHO, Pdfmod is not a good solution, because... 1) - If the document contains page numbering (for example, "page 1/7") pdfmod will broke this. 2) - If any option did work earlier it would work now too. Pdf Options was a good dialog.